# SolrCloud disappears after 15-20 minutes

Tags: solr, solrcloud

**The setup**
We have setup a SolrCloud (Solr version 4.10.4) cluster consisting of 6 servers distributed over 2 datacenters (3 on each DC).

The cluster is setup with 3 shards and a replication factor of 2 and handles one core with 45M documents averaging at about 100GB per shard. There are 3 Zookeeper instances regulating the cluster that reside on 3 of the 6 servers (the ones in the first DC).

The core resides on a  6Gb/s SSD drive on all shards. 
The intra-DC ping time is in the region of 0.3ms, while the inter-DC one is in the region of 3 ms.

The cluster is setup on Tomcat 7.0.61 and Java 7 with an allocated memory of 26GB while each server has 32GB available while each node is configured to contact the zookeeper every 30 seconds.

The cache configuration for each solr node is as follows

```xml
<filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
             size="40000"
             initialSize="40000"
             autowarmCount="0"/>
<queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                 size="50000"
                 initialSize="20000"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>
<documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
               size="2000000"
               initialSize="2000000"
              />
<fieldValueCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
               size="8"
               autowarmCount="8"
               showItems="8" />
```

On top of that we have an API application that performs certain search operations that most of the times look like:

```
q=Fragmento+de+retablo+NOT+DATA_PROVIDER%3A%22CER.ES%3A+Red+Digital+de+Colecciones+de+museos+de+Espa%C3%B1a%22&
rows=12&start=0&
sort=score+desc&
timeAllowed=30000&fl=*%2Cscore&facet.mincount=1
```

We use one or at most to sort parameters (the second one being the unique id of our schema but not in this example).

**The problem**
Our API sends around 5-10 queries per second on the cluster. Even that minimal number of requests after a while overwhelms the cluster and nodes start disappearing while at the same time a lot of disk I/O is observed. We do some manual cache warming for about 10 minutes before we make the core available to the API and we notice that after a while (and before the crash of the cluster) the hit ratio on the caches is 1 for all but the `queryResultCache=0.67` and `documentCache=0.9`, while no evictions happen either. The memory consumption is around 88%.

Any ideas what can be wrong or where we should focus will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you check your solr / zookeeper logs? You may find useful info there.

Comment: hi, I checked the solr and zookeeper logs and it complains about socket timeouts. I also run a number of experiments with different configurations and profiling, and it seems that GC kicks in and pauses the whole cluster

Answer (score 0):

A memory consumption of around 88 percent can quickly jump to 100 and kill the cores.

That happened to us... Look for core dump files in the individual cores logs

SolrCloud is also susceptible to high cpu spikes that can make the ZooKeeper think the node is dead... Recovery is slow and sometimes doesn't happen at all.

You can change the default timeout of the ZooKeeper to prevent this from happening.

You can see this bug for example on the issue...

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5565

From you comment I see that you should probably up the timeout to about 2 minutes.

This comes at a price of course - try to read a bit and understand what it means

https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html

Comment: Hi, I started with extensive profiling of the application, and I think that currently the problem is that there are specific queries (similar to the one I provided) that lead to a sub-optimal deep pagination, that eventually lead to GC with pauses that can last for up until 1 minute.

Comment: I've edited the answer to try and answer your new comment as well